# Change the path search order

Tags: cakephp

This is the current search path order:

```
Element file aside/user-panel.php could not be found.

The following paths were searched:

[1].../vendor/maiconpinto/cakephp-adminlte-theme/templates/element/aside/user-panel.php
[2].../templates/element/aside/user-panel.php
[3].../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/templates/element/aside/user-panel.php
```

How can I change the order so current `[2]` is search as first?

The intention is that I don't want to make an edits in the original plugin templates. I rather want to copy them into the project directories and adapt them there.

**EDIT**

I am using CakePHP 4.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Customize Layout From release 1.0.6**

```
/ src/Controller/AppController.php
use Cake\Core\Configure;

public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
    // Overwrite AppView class
    $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('AdminLTE.AdminLTE');
}
```

After you enable the AdminLTEView class in the AppController.php file, you can overwrite any View file, **only by creating the Plugin/AdminLTE/ folder inside the Template folder**.

For example, to overwrite the elements files, you must create them as follow:

- templates/plugin/AdminLTE/element/nav-top.php
- templates/plugin/AdminLTE/element/aside-main-sidebar.php
- templates/plugin/AdminLTE/element/aside/user-panel.php
- templates/plugin/AdminLTE/element/aside/form.php
- templates/plugin/AdminLTE/element/aside/sidebar-menu.php
- templates/plugin/AdminLTE/element/aside-control-sidebar.php
- templates/plugin/AdminLTE/element/footer.php

read more at plugin doc:

https://github.com/maiconpinto/cakephp-adminlte-theme/wiki/Customize-Layout

Comment: Thank you, this is all correct what you write. I apologise I was not accurate enough with my question. My curiosity is if there is some general function which moves my main project on top of the order list.

Comment: "is if there is some general function which moves my main project". this is it `$this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('AdminLTE.AdminLTE');`  when set this class name, app first look for template files in src/Template/Plugin/AdminLTE/, then in vendor/plugin name, then vendor/cakephp/...

Comment: Are you sure this works? In the documentation are mentioned `.ctp` files which aren't used anymore since CakePHP 4.x. Also, shouldn't it be the `templates/` directory as the structure changed as well. I am now confused. Your code isn't for CakePHP 4.x

Comment: yes, documentation is for 3.x, but you know how to replace patch and file extension for 4.x?

Comment: See my answer. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Salines' asnwer isn't applicable for CakePHP 4.x - see this [upgrade guide](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-0-migration-guide.html). I accepted his answer as Salines put me into the right direction even it isn't answered 100% because I was looking for a general function.

As it's described in the link Salines mentioned https://github.com/maiconpinto/cakephp-adminlte-theme/wiki/Customize-Layout I provide here now the correct paths for CakePHP 4.x

- `templates/plugin/AdminLTE/element/nav-top.php`
- `templates/plugin/AdminLTE/element/aside-main-sidebar.php`
- `templates/plugin/AdminLTE/element/aside/user-panel.php`
- `templates/plugin/AdminLTE/element/aside/form.php`
- `templates/plugin/AdminLTE/element/aside/sidebar-menu.php`
- `templates/plugin/AdminLTE/element/aside-control-sidebar.php`
- `templates/plugin/AdminLTE/element/footer.php`